# how can I set the right R interpreter with rpy2

Tags: python, r, anaconda, environment-variables, rpy2

I have installed R and rpy2 using conda

```
conda install -y rpy2=2.9.1 pyarrow=0.11.0 r-base=3.4.3 r-leaps=3.0
```

That all works well, when I use the ipython interpreter:

```
import rpy2.robjects.packages as rpackages 
leaps = rpackages.importr('leaps')  
base = rpackages.importr('base')
```

However in the preinstalled jupyter notebook clone (Cloudera Datascicence Workbench) the rpy2 seems to default to the preinstalled R installation not the one installed in the conda environment. At least when I try to import the "leaps" library I get the error:

```
RRuntimeError: Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/library/stats/libs/stats.so':
  libRlapack.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

where the right library path should be

```
~/.conda/envs/python3.6/lib/R/library/leaps/libs
```

Can anyone tell me which environment variables I have to tweak to point rpy2 in the right direction?